# how to print using bluetooth thermal printer from web (browser)

Tags: javascript, c#, android, asp.net, printing

i'm using c# native web application and i'm trying to print receipt using thermal Bluetooth printer using an android and my app opened from browser
i already trying using java scrip below

```
    function printDiv(printarea) {
    var printContents = document.getElementById(printarea).innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

    window.print();

    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

and succeed for desktop / PC, and the printer connected using USB and installed driver

but when i try using my android, it doesn't work ( i already connected the printer via Bluetooth)

is that possible to print POS receipt using android web browser that using Bluetooth thermal printer? anyone has good example?

Question 2:

and is that possible to open other android application using a click of a button ( example: if i open facebook from browser, the android will ask, open with facebook app or using browser )

thanks for you help

Comment: Did you found your solution ?